# Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, quantum-computing

When I was reading about quantum algorithms I faced the Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm, I see that if we want to solve that problem in a non-quantum algorithm, our algorithm would have exponential time complexity. Now I want to know what is the time complexity of Deutsch-Jozsa algorithm as a quantum algorithm on quantum computers?

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia the complexity of the quantum algorithm is constant:

> The Deutsch-Jozsa quantum algorithm produces an answer that is always correct with a single evaluation of *f*.

The algorithm itself are just some calculations on quantum states, without any iterations/... so complexity is *O(1)*.